# How to Encrypt the whole structure of a table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing problem regarding the encryption of the structure of a table in phpmyadmin. like i want to see the structure of a table in encrypted form when i export a table from phpmyadmin. means i want that the fields of the table appear in .sql file should be encrpted so that no one can read the information about fields of the table. i have search a lot on google, yahoo but i don't find any solution to do this. Please it will be a great favour. Thanks in advance

the example is here 
basically i have a table name student with fields like name, cnic, dob i want that when i export the whole table into sql file from phpmyadmin the fields name like name, cnic, dob should be appear encrypted. so the user don't able to read them. just i want to do this task

Comment: Having removed the fluff from your question there's one line left, and I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Its not totally clear @Sanaullah but i have posted a suggestion.

Comment: Why not just encrypt the file after your export it?

Comment: Sir siride how to do that thing after exporting a database table in sql file give me some idea.....????

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can encrypt table data while you are saving in `MYSQL`, so that MySQL doesn't even *know* it's encrypted.

> **Result:** Whenever you export table data either from *phpmyadmin*, No one can read that sql or csv file without decypting it.

If you are showing data you can de-crypt it back for getting its actual form.

> Note: If you encrypt your data with any method like *MD5* you can't
>   get its actual form (De-crypt from).

Comment: sir i wannt the whole database file to be encrypted when i export it from phpmyadmin.....???

Comment: No there is not so method @Sanaullah to encrypt whole DB.

Comment: sir basically i have a table name student with fields like name, cnic, dob i want that when i export the whole table into sql file from phpmyadmin the fields name like name, cnic, dob should be appear encrypted. so the user don't able to read them. just i want to do this task